# Remove duplicate objects from an array with Keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, data-structures

How to filter array of objects by property? for example in this array if two or more objects have same properties like **name** and **lastname** I want to remove either of them and leave only unique one in an array. example arr:

```
    [ {name: "George", lastname: "GeorgeLast", age: 12},
      {name: "George", lastname: "GeorgeLast", age: 13},
      {name: "Bob", lastname: "GeorgeLast", age: 12}]
```

result should be either

```
 [ {name: "George", lastname: "GeorgeLast", age: 13},
   {name: "Bob", lastname: "GeorgeLast", age: 12}]
```

or

```
 [ {name: "George", lastname: "GeorgeLast", age: 12},
   {name: "Bob", lastname: "GeorgeLast", age: 12}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the technique shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/1563833), which is:

```
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```

...but using `findIndex` with some criteria rather than just `indexOf`.

```js
let people = [
  { name: "George", lastname: "GeorgeLast", age: 12 },
  { name: "George", lastname: "GeorgeLast", age: 13 },
  { name: "Bob", lastname: "GeorgeLast", age: 12 }
]

let result = people.filter(
  (person, index) => index === people.findIndex(
    other => person.name === other.name
      && person.lastname === other.lastname
  ));
console.log(result);
```

As for whether it keeps 12-year-old George or 13-year-old George, it is a matter of how `findIndex` works, which so happens to return the *first* matching element.  So in your example case it will keep 12-year-old George.

Comment: @ScottFleming, can you please explain the relevance of your comment?  Usually when you have `listeners.findIndex is not a function` it's because `listeners` was a promise that you needed to `await` to get its resultant array, or it was an object `{}` instead of an array `[]`.  But I'm not sure why you're mentioning it in the comment section of this answer (especially with no context), instead of asking a new question of your own.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution.
Here you don't need to iterate through the list n*n/2 times (if I count correctly).
On the other hand, this one looks less concise and uses more memory.
Use whichever you prefer.

```js
const arr = [
  {name: "George", lastname: "GeorgeLast", age: 12},
  {name: "George", lastname: "GeorgeLast", age: 13},
  {name: "Bob", lastname: "GeorgeLast", age: 12}
];

const obj = {}
arr.forEach(v => {
  if (!obj[v.name]) {
    obj[v.name] = {}
  }
  if (!obj[v.name][v.lastname]) {
    obj[v.name][v.lastname] = v;
  }
})

const result = [];
Object.values(obj).forEach(nameObj =>
  Object.values(nameObj).forEach(surnObj => result.push(surnObj))
);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Map object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original insertion order of the keys.

```
   const arr = [
    { name: "George", lastname: "GeorgeLast", age: 12 },
    { name: "George", lastname: "GeorgeLast", age: 13 },
    { name: "Bob", lastname: "GeorgeLast", age: 12 }
    ];
    
    const newMap = new Map();
    arr.forEach((item) => newMap.set(item.name, item));
    console.log([...newMap.values()]);
```